# How to connect an existing SQLite database to a ROOM Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

**Code:**

```
private static UserRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

public static UserRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context) {
if (INSTANCE == null) {
   synchronized (UserRoomDatabase.class) {
       if (INSTANCE == null) {

             /* A database is created here, but is it possible to indicate the 
                path to an existing database here, followed by dependency 
                binding? 
                Or is there another way?*/

   INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
   UserRoomDatabase.class, "user_database")
   .build();
       }
   }
 }
 return INSTANCE;
   }
```

A database is created here, but is it possible to indicate the path to an existing database here, followed by dependency binding? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

My approach is the following: I copy old database tables into the new one (Room) just after Room database is created for the first time

```
 Room.databaseBuilder(app.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, ROOM_DB_NAME)
    .addCallback(new Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase roomDb){
                //  This is called when the database is created for the first time.
                super.onCreate(roomDb);

                OldDatabase oldDatabase = ...// your old database of type SQLiteOpenHelper

                MigrationHelper migrationHelper = new MigrationHelper(oldDatabase,roomDb);
                migrationHelper.doMigrateFromOldToNewDb();

                }
    })
    .build();
```

and the Migration helper class

```
public class MigrationHelper {

private OldDatabase oldDatabase;
SupportSQLiteDatabase roomDb;

public MigrationHelper(OldDatabase oldDatabase, SupportSQLiteDatabase roomDb){
    this.oldDatabase = oldDatabase;
    this.roomDb = roomDb;
}

public void doMigrateFromOldToNewDb(){
    roomDb.beginTransaction();

    copyTableData("table1");
    copyTableData("table2");
    copyTableData("table3");

    roomDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    roomDb.endTransaction();

}

private void copyTableData(String tableName){
    Cursor c = oldDatabase.select("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        StringBuilder columns =  new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder values =  new StringBuilder();

        columns.append(" (");
        values.append(" VALUES (");
        for(int i = 0;i< c.getColumnCount();i++){
            columns.append("`");
            columns.append(c.getColumnName(i));
            columns.append("`");

            if(c.getString(i) != null) {
                values.append("'");
                values.append(c.getString(i));
                values.append("'");
            } else {
                values.append("''");
            }

            if(i < c.getColumnCount()-1){
                columns.append(",");
                values.append(",");
            }
        }
        columns.append(")");
        values.append(")");

        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + columns.toString() + values.toString();
        Log.e("TAG",insertQuery);
        roomDb.execSQL(insertQuery);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Well, I also thought of a way to upgrade the database version through migration, and you implemented it. Thanks. I would like to see another code. Which way did other programmers go? After all, this is an important topic - to make a ready-made database, for example, in the SQLite manager and import it. Why ROOM library did not provide code for ready-made databases ...